# DropDownMenu does not show list of items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

In my View DropDown Menu for Notifications isn't working, I have taken this dropdown menu from a friend. On his project it was showing list of items onclick but in my project it is not showing list of items onclick. kindly guide me through this, image as an output sample is shown below

[image]

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">         
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
                <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
         </ul>            
      </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: why is this tagged asp.net-mvc? youve only posted html

Comment: because I am implementing this thing in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpOption", new List<SelectListItem>{
new SelectListItem{ Text="Daily", Value = "Daily" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="Weekly", Value = "Weekly" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="Monthly", Value = "Monthly" },
}, "-- Select --", new { @class = "dropdown", id = "drpOption" })
```

Try this Code

Comment: sorry my mistake, I have taken this piece of code from my friend. On his project it was showing its list of items onclick but in my project it isn't showing any way... I am updating the question.... I need that glyphicon-bell with dropdown menu ...